# Send Client's IP Address with wp_remote_post()

Tags: wordpress

I want to send Client's IP address with WordPress's wp_remote_post() function. Target URL should recognize Client's IP address instead of Server's IP.

Is it possible?

Comment: here you have an answer how to obtain visitor's IP:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: Thanks kkarpieszuk, but read my question again, I want to forward client's ip to targeted url using in function wp_remote_post()

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the REST service receiving the data. You could try one of the  following:

**Query params**

`$response = wp_remote_get( $url . '?client_ip=' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] );`

**Headers**

`$response = wp_remote_get( $url, [ 'headers' => [ 'client_ip' => $_SERVER[ "REMOTE_ADDR" ] ] );`